# Crystal report: Adding more column to the existed chart

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I'm using Crystal Report 11.5.12.1838.
I wanted to add more column 'Total" for each month to the chart the blow:
 [Chart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYoac.png)
I've tried both Running Total field and the Cross-tab. but it's lead me to nowhere as it's not my expectation.
As Running total field, it's increase the quality by the time, not separate for each month.
As the Cross-tab, it's generated another chart, instead of adding to the existed one.
I'm completely new with this so there may have some trick that i haven't know.
Please help me on this.
High appreciate if any input.

Edit.....................................................................

Please take a look on the Running total of mine: Running Total Configuration I added the summary to the footer before. You can see it in the brown highlighted: Expected chart

As i wanted to add this total column to the chart, but when using Running Total time, it's increase continuously. And the matter is i didn't know how to add more column to the existed chart.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0):

Running total should work but if you are unable to use the running total... Post what have you took in `Evaluate` and `Reset` so that we can see if anythig wrong you have done.

You can follow one more appraoch which is very simple and gives you sum.

Group the report with month

Place the remaining data in details

Now take the summary in group footer by `Right Click field --> insert summary --> take sum to group footer`

Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Whatever Reset setting, it's not match as expectation.

Comment: Then follow another approach as suggested that will work for sure

Comment: Thanks Shiva. I've changed to the Stacked bar type and show the total on top of bars. This resolved my issue

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you...if yes accept it as answer so that others can use